# Random.choice not working correctly python

Tags: python, random

I have the following code for example:

```
n = ['321','243','780']
b = ['12','56','90']
a = ['178', '765', '111']

E = input('Enter Word...')
qw = 1
Code = ('')
E_ready = [E[no:no+qw] for no in range(0, len(E), qw)]
for code in E_Ready:
   letter = random.choice(code)
   Code += letter
```

If you enter the word 'nba' then it will output as 'nba', I want it to output with random elements from each letter's respective list so for example '32112178'

Comment: Actually you do **not** want that, that is really bad design: call-by-name is rather unsafe. You better use a dictionary.

Comment: But `'n'` is not a list, it's a string; `n` is a list.

Comment: I was gonna use a dictionary but I really don't wanna use one, unless you can assign variables to lists in a dictionary.

Comment: I understand that it is handling 'code' as a list, so how can i make it take the value of code and use that

Comment: You should use a dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Willem van Onsem correctly mentioned in the comments:

> "...that is really bad design, call-by-name is rather unsafe. You better use a dictionary."

So, try this:

```
n = {'option1':'321','option2':'243','option3':'780'}
letter = random.choice(list(n.values()))
```

Or, shorter, as Chris has mentioned:

```
d = {'n':[321, 243, 780]}
letter = random.choice(d['n'])
```

Results from `print(letter)` (on both options):

```
321
321
780
243
etc..
```

**EDIT**:

How to add extra variables:

```
n = 'n'
d = {n:[321, 243, 780]}
letter = random.choice(d[n])
q = 'q'
d[q] = [600, 234, 180]
new_letter = random.choice(d[q])
```

Now `print(new_letter)` gives:

```
234
180
180
600
etc..
```

**SECOND EDIT** (which btw is pure bonus since the question turned into a completely different one then first asked.. therefor, it is left unoptimized. Yet, working nonetheless..):

```
import random
d = {'n':[321, 243, 780], 'b':['12','56','90'], 'a':['178', '765', '111']}

E = input('Enter Word...')

inputword = list(E)

for key in d.keys():
    if key in inputword:
        for i in range(len(inputword)):
            if inputword[i] == key:
                try:
                    inputword[i] = str(random.choice(d[key]))
                except:
                    pass

result = ''.join(inputword)
print(result)
```

If input = `nba` then output = `32190111`

If input = `nhhsygbbvvra` then output = `321hhsyg5690vvr178`

Etc..

Comment: oh, I think I can make this work, I'll try it out and reply if it works.

Comment: I still want to use a variable bec. I'm gonna have multiple lists/dictionaries so i need to use sth like this random.choice(list(VariableName.values()))

Comment: Could you update your question with the adapted code you are trying to execute now and the exact error it gives you?

Comment: I just did,  hopefully it helps

Comment: so how do i implement this exactly?

Comment: If you could send me the full code that would be really helpful :D

Comment: This isn't something I normally would do. Please, learn how to be specific when asking a question. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and try to follow it always.

Comment: Sorry it's kinda my first time using this site, so sorry for the trouble but I'm really grateful for your help

Answer (score 1):

Okay, you have a few fundamental issues.
When you want to assign one variable to another then you wouldn't put it in quotes.
So it should be:

```
code = n
```

But actually I'm wondering why you need the variable code at all.
You could simply do

```
import random
code = [ '321', '243', '780' ]
letter = random.choice(code)
print letter
```

Comment: I can't do that bec. in the bigger picture, I will be taking code from a for loop so i want it to take a random element from different lists.

Comment: See Willem van Onsem's comment to the original question, call-by-name is bad design..

Comment: like i.e i have 'a', 'b', 'c' lists, I made a for loop that will return 'a' , 'b' or 'c' so i want it to take a random element out of the respective list.

Comment: @YousefRadwan you really should not do that.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comment, it is better to use something like:

```
d = {'n':[mylist]}
letter = random.choice(d['n'])
```

the problem is that `random.choice` works on strings too... it simply considers them to be a list of characters. in your case the code variable and n are supposed to be exactly the same but are in fact not. You could also do

```
n = [list]
code = n ## only makes any sense, if there 
         ## is a procedure assigns it based on some condition 
letter = random.choice(code)
```